# Save canvas data to browser

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I'm building a very simple drawing app with HTML5 canvas.

Basically, I want the user to be able to draw a line on the canvas, close the browser, come back, and the line is still there.

Is this possible? I have found that you can save a canvas as an image, but would I be able to re-load that image *back into* a fresh canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain to you doing my best.
As you said, you can save the contents of the canvas as an image, but after you do with the image? For a fairly obvious security issue you can not save the image on the user's computer. One method would be to create a server (for example in node.js to always use javascript) and when the user decides to save the drawing the image will be created, it will be sent to the server and it will be loaded into a database connected to the server. But this is a very complex solution, and is only useful in particular conditions, for example if you want the images to be exchanged between users of the app. For your case, and that of most people, it would be enough to save the drawing in the localstorage.

> What is HTML Web Storage?
>   With web storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.

With local storage you can save and read the variables that will remain in the browser.
The value of the variables can only be strings, but no problem!
If you want for example (as in the small project below) to save in the local storage an objects or arrays you can convert them to a string json (if you do not know what is json look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript).
If you want to see the variables that the app saves, for google chrome open the console, go to the Appliaction tab, and you will find them local storage and session storage (another way to store data)
In this small project we save an array of points that make up the drawing. For more information on localstorage here is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
Remember, however, that not all browsers support local storage so this app for older browsers will not work, use chrome and you're okay!

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>App to draw</title>

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            outline: 0;
        }

        #render {
            border: 5px solid rgba(120, 120, 129, 0.452);
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .button {
            border: 2px solid;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 100px;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .save {
            border-color: #4CAF50;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        .save:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }

        .clear {

            border-color: #008CBA;
            background-color: #008CBA;
            color: white;
        }

        .clear:hover {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Simple app for drawing made with  by Niccolo'</h3>
        <canvas id="render"></canvas>
        <div class="tools">
            <input type="button" class="button save" value="save" onclick="canvas.saveDrawing()">
            <input type="button" class="button clear" value="clear" onclick="canvas.clearDrawing()">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
"use strict";

//mouse position
let mouseX,
  mouseY,
  isDragging = false;

//Canvas
class Canvas {
  constructor() {
    //html canvas
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("render");
    //context
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    //dimensions
    this.width = this.canvas.width = 300;
    this.height = this.canvas.height = 300;
    //Points that make up the simple design
    //He goes to look in the localstorage, if he does not find it he creates a simple array
    this.points = this.getDrawing() || [];
    //color
    this.color = "black";
    this.weight = 5;
  }

  update() {
    //If the user is dragging the mouse inside the canvas, he creates points
    if (isDragging) {
      if (
        mouseX >= 0 &&
        mouseX <= this.width &&
        mouseY >= 0 &&
        mouseY <= this.height
      ) {
        this.points.push({
          x: mouseX,
          y: mouseY
        });
      }
    }
  }
  draw() {
    //delete the background
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.height, this.width);
    //set the color
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    //draw points
    for (let point of this.points) {
      this.ctx.save();
      this.ctx.translate(point.x, point.y);
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(0, 0, this.weight, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      this.ctx.fill();
      this.ctx.restore();
    }
  }
  //save in the localstorage the points that make up the design
  saveDrawing() {
    const json = JSON.stringify(this.points);
    localStorage.setItem("drawing", json);
  }
  //search for points in the localstorage
  getDrawing() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("drawing"));
  }
  //clean the drawing pad
  clearDrawing() {
    this.points = [];
  }
}

//Canvas
const canvas = new Canvas();

//Events
window.addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
  let rect = canvas.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
  mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;
});
window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => (isDragging = true));
window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => (isDragging = false));

//main function in loop
function main() {
  canvas.update();
  canvas.draw();

  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
//The program starts here
main();
```

Good luck with your project :-D

Comment: This is one of the most detailed answers I've ever gotten, thank you very much!
I don't know how I didn't think to save the actual points drawn, and then just redraw them on load. Works perfectly with my project.